# Where do I create my ssh directory?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

So I want to generate an SSH key for my Digital Ocean droplet. Do I create the SSH directory/file in my project directory? Or do I just create it in Desktop? E.g. say the project I'm working on is in `Desktop/project`. Do I just `cd` to that folder and then create the SSH directory? (and then create the actual ssh file in that ssh directory)

Answer (score 1):

Normally `~/.ssh` it the location of public/private keys on a Mac or Linux machine for ssh related commands.